# How can I add a plot that covers the whole data ignoring grouping?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a dataframe with a variable `delta2` that I cut as `above and below 0.8` and plot `var1 v/s var2` for the 2 groups. But I also want to add the case for `delta2 = -Inf,Inf`, basically include the entire dataset and compare the same `var1 v/s var2`. How can I proceed?

```
sm$dclass <- cut(sm$d, breaks=c(-Inf, 0.8, Inf), labels=c("delta2 < 0.8 ","delta2 >= 0.8"))

ggplot(sm, aes(var1, var2)) +
  facet_wrap(~ dclass) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=factor(dclass))) +
  stat_density_2d()+
  scale_colour_discrete()
```

[image]

Comment: Since `sm` is not found on others' systems, can you either share some of your data (using `dput(head(x))`), generate some random data (can be much larger!), or adapt your problem to a standard dataset in R? Without this, anything you get will be untested at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique is to add to the existing plot with redefined data. For instance:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, col=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_density_2d() +
  geom_point(data=transform(mtcars, cyl="all")) +
  stat_density_2d(data=transform(mtcars, cyl="all")) +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

[image: mtcars scatterplot grouped by cylinder, adding fourth facet that includes all data]

Comment: You might also try using the full data as "background" by using a version of the data with the faceting variable removed:  `geom_point(data = subset(mtcars, select = -cyl), 
             aes(disp, mpg),
             color = "gray70") +`

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. one last question: How would I add the `stat_density2d()` part? I added the aesthetics. But that still led to the statdensity plots not being added to all the subplots...

Comment: Literally just add another `stat_density_2d` with its own `data=` argument. That's the point, just provide a repeat of the stat/geom that has its own data. (I moved the `aes(...)` to the top line for efficiency ... not required, just an option.)